# In Ernest Goes to Camp did the Chief speak an actual language?

Tags: character, dialogue, ernest-goes-to-camp

In the film [Ernest Goes to Camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Goes_to_Camp) when the Cheif was speaking seems to have been using real [Plains Indian Sign Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plains_Indian_Sign_Language) based on the Wikipedia article for the movie. But that's just the sign language, so I was wondering does he speak an actual language or is it all just made up?